# Global file initialization in flask- python

Tags: python, flask

I have been googling to find how to create a global file, which will open till my application is completed . Need to write the output of all modules in a view in single file. so that users can download this file as a report once application is completed running from Front end. This is the class I have created

```
import time


class FileOperations:
    def __init__(self):

        self.current_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        self.outfile = open("reports/username_" + self.current_time + ".txt", 'w')
        self.outfile.write("Final Report \n")
        self.outfile.write("*****************")
```

I want this file to get it generated when the application start running & should be available for all modules

Answer (score 0):

A context manager is a way to safely handle operations such as writing to file. It also allows you to better trace when file opens or closes.
I suggest you take the time when the application starts, and reuse that file as I take it you intended. That's probably "safer" than keeping the file open.

```
def get_time():
    global start_time
    start_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

def write_to_file():
    with open('reports/username_{}.txt'.format(start_time), 'a') as f:
      f.write("Final Report \n")
      f.write("*****************")

if 'start_time' not in globals():
    get_time()
```

The conditional will run each time the module is imported. By checking if its already defined in the module scope, we make sure to only define it once.